# Can you define which document gets created with Alt + Ctrl + N in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, document-setup, template

`Ctrl Alt N` in Illustrator bypasses the New Document dialog and immediately creates a new document for you. Is there any way to set this up to always spawn a specific document (template) when you press that shortcut?

Comment: Usually the answer is no what you experience is what you get. But you can record an action that does specify the document

Comment: @joojaa This seemed great in theory but there seemed to be two issues with it. 1. you can't specify a document to be opened with actions, only have the action activate the Open dialog, or am I missing something? 2. You can't bind Ctrl + Alt + N to the action. I ultimately came to the conclusion that the best solution to achive the desired goal was that in my comment on cruciformhawk7's answer below.

Comment: no i can get it to work what version of illustrator. Yes you can not bind actions to anything other than function keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> creates a new document but duplicates your current document settings.

I guess it would be better to create a new template and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and choose that template, or create a new document with the options you want and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> as much as you want.

Comment: +1 Yes. The shortcut merely opens a **new document based on the last opened document**. So, open the document with the document profile you *want* and then you can repeat the shortcut all you want for that same set up.

Comment: Thanks all for replies. I'll mark this as the answer. However, I still think this operation is sub-optimal. For Win users, here's one way to have Ctrl+Alt+N always spawn a specific document template. It involves AutoHotkey, which you should use anyway ;). Pardon the crappy formatting (make a new line by the § characters and remove them from your script):

`#IfWinActive ahk_exe Illustrator.exe ahk_class ahk_class illustrator`§
`; Quickly create new document without opening the New Document dialog`§
`^!N::`§
`Run, Drive:\path\to\your template document.ait`§
`return`§
`#IfWinActive`